# Database tables for tennis court booking system

Tags: mysql, uml, database-schema, class-diagram

I'm trying to find the best implementation of class diagram and database structure for football court management. The system have three actors:

1. Super Admin : manage everything with all privileged (web back-office)
2. Court Owner : can create a Football Club that may have more than one stadium (web back-office)
3. Player: who can review a club and book an available stadium (mobile)

My problems  are :

1. Since the three actors have the same properties, I don't need the  "extend" relation between "user" and "owner", "player", "admin", but also I can't only have the class "user" because not all users can submit a review and only the owner can add a club...  so how to manage the privilege of different users who have the same properties ? and do I need the User group table that can help me to know the group of each user ("owner", "admin", "player") ? (I see that Joomla and Wordpress use a user group table)
2. The Club can have many stadiums (courts) in the majority of cases they are identical so should In my solution bellow is it correct to have two classes "club" and "stadium" and put the common information (city , latitude, longitude) inside the class "club" ?
3. Take in consideration that player can book a stadium of a club and the club have another available stadiums that can be booked is my solution bellow correct ?

Please I need your guidance and suggestion of the best implementation for a football clubs management where:

1. There is three actors ("player", "admin", "club owner")
2. Each actor have different privileged (only owner can create a club, only player can book and review...)
3. Avery Club can have many stadiums and player can book one of them or many, and we need to keep track of the availability of other stadiums of the same club.

   Here is what I have tried:

   [image: Class diagram sport club management]

Edit link : https://creately.com/diagram/iaqn8ddo/T1IfqHRrhGcHYPihjOwMIQSwM%3D

View Link : http://creately.com/diagram/example/iaqn8ddo/Copy%2Bof%2BTakwira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not look too bad.

1. You already have classes for the actors. So that's done.
2. The "privileges" can be modeled by assigning the specialized classes the according methods. That is: `Owner` has a `createClub()` method and `Player` has `book()` etc.
3. You need a `Booking` class that keeps track of the bookings made by `Player`

One observation: the composition from `Stadium` (you have a typo in the name) to `SportsClub` does not seem to make sense. A club is not composed of stadiums. In best case it's composed of members. Replace it with an association and use `ownedStadium` as role.

Comment: You also may have wrong multiplicities. I'm pretty sure a sportsclub usually has more than one owner, and I know clubs who share their stadium, which is not possible in your design.

Comment: @Thmas : Thank you for your replay, actually I want to be sure that it's fine to have an empty class in the diagram of classes since in my case the three users have the same information. Also the class "Reservation"  is my "Booking" , and my be I mean by club a "Complex", a group of stadiums, that's why I put a composition relation.

Comment: @ Geert: thank you for your answer, Actually you are right, Sport clubs can have more than one owner, but in our case we assume that just one owner manage the club from the web back-end, so let's say the relation name is "manage" so only one user can be assigned to a club management system. I am still open to any suggestion in the design.

Comment: Well, an empty class is ok since it inherits from `User`. You should remember that naming is crucial. Things are only what they are named. Crossing at cherry-green is likely illegal.